# How to reduce the QR decoding time without changing the size of input image?

Tags: java, android, qr-code, zxing

I have a java application that extracts a QR tag from an image, re-scales it to 768x768 and sends to the decoder for decoding. I am using ZXing via intent for decoding, but it is way too slow!

It takes about 6-8 seconds for decoding the QR. Is there any way to reduce this time without changing the size of the QR image?

Thanks!

Comment: Is that 6-8 seconds for just the QR->data process, or 6-8 seconds for FINDING the qr code inside the original image+extracting+resizing+decoding?

Comment: I am not sure what you are doing then, because the app decodes frames of about 800x600 in under 100ms, even on a phone. On a PC it's milliseconds.
You haven't said anything about what platform, what options, etc. but you're definitely doing something wrong then

Comment: @MarcB Yes! i meant that only, 6-8 seconds for the whole process. I apologize for not being clear. I have tested and figured out that i can't optimize the extraction + resizig part. So, i wanted to reduce the decoding time.

@ SeanOwen The whole process takes about 6-8 seconds, QR is extracted from a 3264x2448 image, using javacv on a core i5 system.

Thanks for the replies, i checked out a few lower resolution images around 2MP and i am getting result within 2 seconds. :)